# Eager Loading Nested Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I have the following models:

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game

  has_many :session_players
  has_many :players, through: :session_players
end

class SessionPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :session
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :session_players
  has_many :sessions, through: :session_player
end
```

In the erb file I am trying to loop over all sessions, displaying some info about the session and displaying nested data about each player for that session.

The relevant code in the erb file is:

```
<% @sessions.each do |session| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= session.name %></td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <% session.session_players.each do |session_player| %>
                <!-- problem line below -->
                <tr><td><%= session_player.player.name %> (<%= session_player.placing %>)</td></tr>
            <% end %>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that I cannot pull data off of both the player and the session_player object due to a null exception when getting the `name` value off of the `session_player.player.name` call. The call to the `session_player.placing` succeeds.

I believe this to be a lazy loading issue as I can retrieve the value of `session_player.player.name` while debugging the code, just not when running it. I tried eager loading the data by trying various includes combinations in the controller but it did not make a difference:

`@sessions = Session.includes(:session_players => :player).all`

Comment: The reason why you get null exception when getting the name value off of the `session_player.player.name` is due to that specific `session_player` doesn't have a `player` associated with it. Make sure all values of `player_id` field in `session_players` table are **not null** and match with the `ids` of `players` table

Comment: This was the problem. One of the later values was null. I thought eager loading would reveal the problem in the controller instead of when resolving the data in the template but that was not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was correct, but the data I was populating it with was not. One of the values was null later in the list of data. This was not being caught until the data was being accessed during template rendering. Eager loading had no effect on when the data when the exception occurred.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
@sessions = Session.joins(:session_players)
```

Or to avoid N+1

```
@sessions = Session.includes(:session_players)
```

You can use `try` to define when there is no relation

```
<% session.session_players.each do |session_player| %>
   <!-- problem line below -->
   <tr><td><%= session_player.try(:player).try(:name) %> (<%= session_player.placing %>)</td></tr>
<% end %>
```